# Filter numeric and specific value from excel column - python

Tags: python, excel, filter, numeric

I have a column with mixed values as below:

[image: Column with numeric and textual values]

I want to filter the column and remove the highlighted rows. I can achieve removing the string starting from "b0" but I am unable to apply filter to only numeric values. dtype is object of the columns. Below code does not work for me nor do I want to create a separate column to convert string to numeric.

```
pd.to_numeric(df['Mixed Data'],errors='coerce').min()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if all the values in your DF are strings. If the highlighted numeric values (the ones without `b0`) are actually ints instead of strings, you can drop the second part of the df conditional.

Reference material [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-drop-rows-that-contain-a-specific-string-in-pandas/)

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(
    {
        "Mixed Data": [
            "100 socks",
            "3467867327",
            "94746723892",
            "400 order",
            "oils",
            "essentials",
            "b01232435",
            "b0054543543543",
            "garments",
            "787 sales",
        ],
        "Some other column": [
            "a",
            "b",
            "c",
            "d",
            "e",
            "f",
            "g",
            "h",
            "i",
            "j",
        ],
    }
)
df = df[df["Mixed Data"].str.startswith("b0") == False][
    df["Mixed Data"].str.isnumeric() == False
]
print(df)
```

output

```
   Mixed Data Some other column
0   100 socks                 a
3   400 order                 d
4        oils                 e
5  essentials                 f
8    garments                 i
9   787 sales                 j
```

Comment: No this is not working for me as I am loosing data for other string values also. I just want to drop the strings starting with B0 so that works fine but unable to drop the cell which only contains integers

Comment: so the question here becomes: what values are dropped that you don't want dropped?

Comment: the non highlighted ones should stay and the highlighted ones should drop but with your code I get an output where all values are dropped